# Regex boundaries JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Finding it difficult to match exact word cases. e.g I want the text file to only match the whole word "cent" instead of "accent". In the example below the hasString method should return false. Instead of finding "ites" in the word "mites" and returning true.

Have been googling and trying different things like regEx \b boundaries.

Please see code below, thanks :)

```
var word  ="ites";

$.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpog19901/Countdown/master/text/english3.txt", function(contents) {
           //contents variable now contains the contents of the textfile as string

           //check if file contains the word entered by user
           var hasString = contents.includes(\b+word+\b);

           //outputs true if contained, else false
           console.log(hasString);
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

`includes` takes a substring.

use something like this

```js
console.log(/\bword\b/.test('my superword is hello'));
console.log(/\bword\b/.test('my word is hello'));
```

Comment: hmmm trying to figure out how to do it like this but doing .test on the text file from it's URL

Comment: just pass that to the call to `test` @cpog90

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I'm pretty much a beginner but is this what you mean:

Comment: $.get("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cpog19901/Countdown/master/text/english3.txt", function(contents) {
             //contents variable now contains the contents of the textfile as string

             //check if file contains the word entered by user
             var hasString = contents.test(/\bnewWord\b/);

             //outputs true if contained, else false
             console.log(hasString);
           });